# Does the adjunction of comparison of equality “as much as” make preposition-stranding impossible?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, relative-clauses

Is it possible to strand the preposition in this sentence: “she often thought about the solar system, to which she sometimes felt she belonged, as much as to her own city”? This is from a French text I am trying to translate and I would like to know if both versions are correct.
With preposition-stranding, it would be: “She often thought about the solar system, which she sometimes felt she belonged to, as much as to her own city.”
I have the impression (but I am not a native speaker) that the adjunction of the comparison of equality make the sentence syntactically awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences, that with the preposition stranded and that with the preposition pied-piped, are equally acceptable: the following comparative does not affect acceptability.

To my ear, however, both sentences are also equally awkward. Contemporary English discursive prose has largely turned its back on deep embedding, subordinate-within-subordinate-within-..., and has come to prefer more paratactic construction.